# When is the logarithmic generating function of relative compositions negative at −1?

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions

Suppose $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. Define the **logarithmic generating function** of $f$ to be
$$
L_{f}(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(k) \frac{x^k}{k}.
$$

This is in contrast to the exponential generating function which is
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(k) \frac{x^k}{k!}.
$$

Suppose for $0 \notin A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ we define the **$A$-relative composition function**
$$
S(n, A)(k) = |\{(a_i)_{0 \leq i < k} \colon (\forall i < k)\, a_i \in A\text{ and }\sum_{i < k} a_i = n\}|
$$
i.e. $S(n, A)(k)$ is the number of compositions of $n$ of length $k$ all of whose elements are in $A$.

One can show that if $A = \{\ell \cdot k\colon  k>0\}$ then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$
L_{S(n, A)}(-1) \leq 0,
$$

i.e.

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty S(n, A)(k) \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \leq 0.
$$

Are there conditions on $A$ (other than the one given above) which will ensure for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $L_{S(n, A)}(-1) \leq 0$? I am especially interested in the case where $1 \in A$ (but also interested in the general case).